# move style of material ui to another file in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm writing an app with material-ui, React and Typescript.
the standard code of `<Grid>` is

```
<Grid
  container
  direction="row"
  justifyContent="center"
  alignItems="center"
/>
```

after prettier formatted, which occupied too many lines. I prefer a code style like

```
<Grid props={"grid-root"}/>
```

```
grid-root: {
  container
  direction="row"
  justifyContent="center"
  alignItems="center"
}
```

so i can move the style code to another file.

Any Suggestion is appreciate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like that

```
const GridProps = {
    container: true,
    direction: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'
}

<Grid {...GridProps} />
```

Here is the working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-leftpad-n7mup?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried and got an error message. `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'GridItemsAlignment | undefined'.  TS2769 ` at `<Grid>`

Comment: `const GridProps: GridProps = {}` works, Thanks again

Comment: oh, you are in TypeScript, I forgot

Comment: If you like my answer or you got any help from my answer, don't forget to consider up-vote and check this answer as the best answer for you by clicking on the right arrow, thanks!

Comment: I accept your answer but can't vote it since I don't have enough reputation. I think i need spend more time on stack overflow

Comment: No problem, thanks for accepting my answer

Answer (score 0):

If it is something you are planning on reusing think about adding it in your theme as a mixin.

```js
// theme.js (or whatever you have for your theme)
const theme = createTheme({
  mixins: {
    gridProps: {
      container: true,
      direction: 'row',
      justifyContent: 'center',
      alignItems: 'center'
    },
  },
})

// component file
import { Grid, useTheme } from '@material-ui/core'

const component = () => {
  const theme = useTheme();

  render(
    <Grid {...theme.mixins.gridProps}>

    </Grid>
  )
}
```

Comment: looks like a more elegant solution. I will try it. thanks